# 2 C-printfs of the same variable print different values

Tags: c++, variables, printf

I want to print a set of variables and have tried out two uses of `printf`.

```
...
uint32_t valueFromVirtualFpgaMemory = 0;
uint32_t valueReference1 = 0;
uint32_t valueCalculated = 0;
...
valueCalculated = XYZ.data.abcOutputInt[4].abcInt[42]; 
...
printf("valueFromVirtualFpgaMemory     : %u (stubbed, dummy value)\n",
       valueFromVirtualFpgaMemory);
printf("reference value 1 (recomposed) : %u\n", valueReference1);
printf("reference value 2              : %u\n", abcRefData2Values[4].abcRefInt[42]);
printf("calculated value               : %u\n\n", valueCalculated);

printf("valueFromVirtualFpgaMemory     : %u (stubbed, dummy value)\n"
       "reference value 1 (recomposed) : %u\n"
       "reference value 2              : %u\n"
       "calculated value               : %u\n\n",
       valueFromVirtualFpgaMemory, valueReference1,
       brsRefData2Values[4].abcRefInt[42], valueCalculated);
```

The value printed for `calculated value` is different:

```
valueFromVirtualFpgaMemory     : 3535786687 (stubbed, dummy value)  
reference value 1 (recomposed) : 4294955712  
reference value 2              : 4294955712  
calculated value               : 3535786687  

valueFromVirtualFpgaMemory     : 3535786687 (stubbed, dummy value)  
reference value 1 (recomposed) : 4294955712  
reference value 2              : 4294955712  
calculated value               : 4294955712
```

Can anyone explain the difference?

Comment: we have no idea what any of your variables are or how they got their values

Comment: Perhaps `uint32_t` is not compatible with `unsigned int` on your system (use `"%" PRIu32` instead of `"%u"`)? Perhaps because `valueCalculated` is not initialized, so you have undefined behavior?

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that you have the right variables in the right order, and that there isn't one that's doubles somewhere?

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with how you call printf in the second case? I mean printf accepted parameters are (const char*, ...), and you put several strings there one after another. Are you sure it's valid?

Comment: @ZenJ: in C, consecutive literal strings are always automatically concatenated.

Comment: @jxh: thank you, I have tried out: `printf ("calculated value : %"PRIu32"\n\n", valueCalculated);` and get: filename.cpp:161:10: warning: invalid suffix on literal; C++11 requires a space between literal and identifier [-Wliteral-suffix] printf ("calculated value : %u"PRIu32"\n\n", valueCalculated); ^   [Rainer] where "^" points to the first quotation mark

Comment: @jxh: continued: /ephemeral/home/c198065/git/5gl1sw/C_Test/SC_PHY/UnitTest/Dl‌​/test_sequences_mana‌​gement.cpp:161:47: error: expected ´)´ before ´PRIu32´ printf ("calculated value : %u"PRIu32"\n\n", valueCalculated); ^ [Rainer] where "^" points to the "P"

Comment: @jxh: I have checked: The variable is initialized. I have updated the code snippet of my question and added the initialization.

Comment: Compiler Information:
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-redhat-linux
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-4) (GCC)

Comment: That means 1. you're using C++, not C, and 2. you forgot to include the header that defines `PRIu32`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not post the definitions of the variables used in your code fragment.

If any of one `valueFromVirtualFpgaMemory`, `valueReference1`, `brsRefData2Values[4].abcRefInt[42]` or `valueCalculated` has a type larger than `int`, the behavior is undefined, possibly explaining inconsistent output from the different calls to `printf`.

Given the output produced, it is very unlikely that `int` be 16 bits, but if it were, `%u` would be incorrect for type `uint32_t`. For complete portability, you should use `%"PRIu32"` for this type. The `printf` and `scanf` formats for the types defined in `<stdint.h>` are defined in `<inttypes.h>`.

EDIT: if `abcRefData2Values[4].abcRefInt[42]` is a complex number, you cannot use `%u` to print its value.

Comment: You should probably mention which header provides `PRIu32`.

Comment: @chqrlie: I have added the other definitions.

Comment: @chqrlie: I have replaced `%u` with `%"PRIu32"`, but I get: /ephemeral/home/c198065/git/5gl1sw/C_Test/SC_PHY/UnitTest/Dl/test_sequences_management.cpp:165:10: warning: invalid suffix on literal; C++11 requires a space between literal and identifier [-Wliteral-suffix]
  printf ("calculated value with PRIu32    : %"PRIu32"\n\n", valueCalculated);

Comment: @chqrlie: continued ...
/ephemeral/home/c198065/git/5gl1sw/C_Test/SC_PHY/UnitTest/Dl/test_sequences_management.cpp: In member function \u2018virtual void TEST_Dl_sequences_management_Test::testBody()\u2019:
/ephemeral/home/c198065/git/5gl1sw/C_Test/SC_PHY/UnitTest/Dl/test_sequences_management.cpp:165:46: error: expected \u2018)\u2019 before \u2018PRIu32\u2019
  printf ("calculated value with PRIu32    : %"PRIu32"\n\n", valueCalculated);

Comment: @Rainer: You did not post the definition of `abcRefData2Values[4].abcRefInt[42]`. It might have a type that is different from `int` or `unsigned`.

Comment: yes, it is a complex number. But still, the point is that a different order leads to different output ...
You rang a bell, I have implemented
`    printf ("siteof brsRefData2Values[4].brsRefInt[42]: %u\n\n", sizeof (brsRefData2Values[4].brsRefInt[42]));`
and I see: **sizeof brsRefData2Values[4].brsRefInt[42]: _8_** -> I have to prepare the value to be printed completely different in order to compare. Thank you !

Comment: @chqrlie: Thank you, you pointed me into the right direction. Addressing that complex variable as %u in a printf was rubbish. I am addressing its real and imaginary part now and have correct output. Thanks to all who have read and contributed. That `%"PRIu32"` thing is interesting and might help me one day in a different project.

Comment: I CLOSE THIS QUESTION.

Comment: @chqrlie: Done with huge delay, sorry for that, but better late than never. Thank you again very very much !